Why do the list of special-characters and the source-editing button not work in the official CKEditor 5 build?
I made a build of CKEditor 5 based on Decoupled document on the official website: https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/


But 2 buttons do not work in this build: Special characters (empty list) and Source.
The build ckeditor5-41.3.1-tnhriujfhl8s.zip is here or you can create build youtself: ckeditor5-41.3.1-tnhriujfhl8s.zip
Why are the buttons not working as expected and how can I fix them?
Thanks!

Found this: SourceEditing plugin not working with decoupled document editor example downloaded from online-builder #12150 : https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/12150

If I build the ClassicEditor, the Source button works, but the list of SpecialCharacters is still empty. Besides, I need a Decoupled document.

I created Classic build, but the CSS broke down. A nightmare!

In Classic build, the Source button works but does not make changes.

Everything was solved with CKEditor technical support. The quesiton is closed.
